# Kafka setting vip address to kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, broker, virtual-ip-address

hi has anyone been successful putting a vip in front of vms kafka cluster?

I want  to route a client to a different kafka nodes.

Comment: clients connect to indiivdual brokers, anyway, so not seeing how this would help... What issues are you running into, though?

Comment: want to add kafka in DNs server and for that we need a vip address

Comment: It's possible, yes. We [use ELB addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38666795/does-kafka-support-elb-in-front-of-broker-cluster) where I work. But again, individual broker addresses are _eventually_ going to be returned directly to the client

Comment: Yes, we use a VIP for bootstrap but it's a fundamental property of Kafka that after initial bootstrap, all clients (producer and consumer) talk directly to the individual brokers which are topic/partition leaders